# htaccess redirect loop if file does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am sure this has a simple solution but I have hit a wall. I am trying to use htaccess to redirect from a query string variable to an html page with the variable as the file name.

example: DOMAIN_NAME/pages/44 would redirect to DOMAIN_NAME/pages/44.html

This works fine unless the file does not exist. If the file does not exist I get something like this.

example: DOMAIN_NAME/pages/45 result is DOMAIN_NAME/pages/45.html.html.html.html.html and so on until the broswer stops the loop.

below is my htaccess code:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/?$ /pages/$1.html [R,L]`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this condition to your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/?$ /pages/$1.html [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. One more question if you don't mind. What would I use if I also wanted to check for an additional parameter?`/pages/$1.html#PARAM=VALUE`

Comment: @Jason you can't check against URL fragments in htaccess. Anything after the `#` in the URL isn't even sent to the server